# View Files from mirrored RAID outside the device

Tags: raid, system, disk

The Product I have is a [Western Digital My Book](http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wd_mybook_world_1tb_06.jpg)

The device has stopped working but there is nothing wrong with either of the two mirrored drives. I would like to take out the two mirrored hard drives, and recover the data if at all possible.  How would I go about this on ubuntu 11.10?  Both of the drives are recognized but I can not see the data anywhere. The relevant software I have on the system are: **Disk Utility** and a terminal application called **mdadm**.  I am trying to be cautious and not accidentally wipe the data.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the individual raid component partitions (if they were RAID 1), but this will change the contents of the partitions, so, be careful if you ever have to add them to a RAID set again. Just mount them by hand (`mount` command)